# MySQLi while loop returning empty array.

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Ok I am making a ticket system, here is the code for the sql query and while loop:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 0) {
    header('Location: /tickets');
}

$username = array();
$message = array();
$timestamp = array();
$status = array();
$subject = array();

while (var_dump($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))) {
    $username[] = $row['username'];
    $message[] = $row['message'];
    $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];
    $subject[] = $row['subject'];
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $new_message = $_POST['message'];

    $new_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $new_message);

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(
    NULL,
    '".$id."',
    '".$username."',
    '".$subject."',
    '1',
    '".date('H M H:i')."',
    '".$new_message."'
    )");
}

?>

<h2>Unique Ticket ID: <?php echo $id; ?></h2>

<?php

foreach ($message as $msg) {
    echo '
    <div class="ticket-message clearfix">
        <h4>'.$username.' ['.$timestamp.']</h4>
        <p>'.$msg.'</p>
    </div>';
}
```

If I try to array print or echo any of these results, it prints "Array" and nothing else. I have a var_dump in place and this is the result:

```
array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" 
           ["ticket_id"]=> string(10) "TICK_71323" 
           ["username"]=> string(6) "Jordan" 
           ["subject"]=> string(14) "ticket subject" 
           ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
           ["timestamp"]=> string(13) "Thu May 12:34" 
           ["message"]=> string(16) "ticket message " 
        }
```

Clearly the data is there to be extracted right? Why can't I get the values properly?

Comment: `exit` after your `header()`

Answer (score -1):

$username, $message and so on are arrays so you need to access them using an index, try this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 0) {
    header('Location: /tickets');
}

$username = array();
$message = array();
$timestamp = array();
$status = array();
$subject = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $username[] = $row['username'];
    $message[] = $row['message'];
    $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];
    $subject[] = $row['subject'];
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $new_message = $_POST['message'];

    $new_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $new_message);
for($i=0;$i<count($username);$i++)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(
    NULL,
    '".$id."',
    '".$username[$i]."',
    '".$subject[$i]."',
    '1',
    '".date('H M H:i')."',
    '".$new_message."'
    )");
}
}
```

This will insert a ticket for each username... also $id variable don't know from where it comes... maybe has to be retrieved in while bucle. Another aproach:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 0) {
    header('Location: /tickets');
}

$username = "";
$message = "";
$timestamp = "";
$status = "";
$subject = "";

if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $message = $row['message'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $new_message = $_POST['message'];

    $new_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $new_message);

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(
    NULL,
    '".$id."',
    '".$username."',
    '".$subject."',
    '1',
    '".date('H M H:i')."',
    '".$new_message."'
    )");
}
```

If only a row is present in $query recordset.

Comment: the $id variable comes from earlier on in the document from a GET Request. It defines the Ticket ID that groups these records together

Comment: Then just try the posted code... I guess second aproach is what you need.